# Postman Post request to NodeJS server does not give me the files properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Good morning. I'm developing a portfolio app with projects. I did a mongoDB database and a NodeJS and express conexion to this database. I'm doing a controller with a method that allows me to upload a image to the database. I did this method, but when I use it with PostMan, the image is uploaded to the folder I indicate, but the files arguments don't appear and I need then to upload to the database.

I upload the code

Controller

```
uploadImage: function(req, res){
    var projectId = req.params.id;
    var fileName = "Imagen no subida...";

    if(req.files){
        return res.status(200).send({
            files: req.files
        });
    }else{
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: fileName
        });
    }
}
```

Routes

```
 'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var ProjectController = require('../controllers/project');

var router = express.Router();

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart({ uploadDir: './uploads' });

router.get('/home', ProjectController.home);
router.post('/test', ProjectController.test);
router.post('/save-project', ProjectController.saveProject);
router.get('/project/:id', ProjectController.getProject);
router.get('/projects', ProjectController.getProjects);
router.put('/project/:id', ProjectController.updateProject);
router.delete('/project/:id', ProjectController.deleteProject);
router.post('/upload-image/:id', multipartMiddleware ,ProjectController.uploadImage);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// cargar archivo Rutas
var routes = require('./routes/project');

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS

// Rutas
app.use('/api', routes);

// exportar
module.exports = app;
```

PostMan

I use form-data and I add an image.

Response:

```
{
  "files": {}
}
```

I think in files JSON there are differents params to upload image to the dataBase, like filePath, fileName...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `req.files.file` not `req.files`

If `req.files.file` does not exist, try to `console.log(req)`, and `console.log(req.files)` to trace the file

---

### Update

check that the Content-Type in the headers sections in postman is `"multipart/form-data"`

[image]

then you can find your file in `req.files.image`, as you name it `image` in `form-data` body section

hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thank you. I was surfing in the internet yesterday and I saw a tutorial to do the same with multer. I did it and it works. I put the code to help people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.
I did the two things, but when I do the `console.log(req.files)` the response is `{}`, and when I do `console.log(req.files.file)` the response is `undefined`.
I don't know what happens, I'm using a .jpg extension image.

Again thank you

Comment: I've update my answer, could you check it?, also you don't need to write a new answer each time, just leave a comment in my answer

Answer (score 0):

thank you.
I send you an image of the PostMan request. I send you in i.stack because is the only way I can send the image.
  [![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHDog.png][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
// Multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, res, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now())
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

The function:

```
uploadImage: function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.file);
}
```

The request:

```
router.post('/upload-image/:id', upload.single('image'), ProjectController.uploadImage);
```